# How to get item's detail info(like attack power, agility..) from WOWARMORY?

Tags: xml, data-mining, world-of-warcraft

I already know that parse the wowarmoy's xml to get the data.
But there are some data that I can't find where to get.

Like this url "http://www.wowarmory.com/item-info.xml?i=40155".

```
<itemInfo>
 <item canAuction="1" icon="inv_jewelcrafting_gem_39" id="40155" level="80" name="Reckless Ametrine" quality="4" type="Orange">
  <cost buyPrice="360000" sellPrice="90000"/>
  <vendors>
    <creature area="Trial of the Crusader" classification="0" heroic="1" id="33290" maxLevel="80" minLevel="80" name="Jillian McWeaksauce" title="The Cutest McWeaksauce" type="Humanoid"/>
  </vendors>
  <createdBy>
    <spell icon="inv_misc_gem_01" id="66574" name="Reckless Ametrine">

      <reagent count="1" icon="inv_jewelcrafting_gem_33" id="36931" name="Ametrine" quality="4"/>
    </spell>
  </createdBy>
</item>
</itemInfo>
```

The xml contains informations like name, id, quality, type but the detail attribute like spell power, haste rating.
But open this url in browser we can of course see these detail information.

So does anyone know how/where to get the detail information like attack power, spell power of an item.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how.
Just parse this url: "http://www.wowarmory.com/item-tooltip.xml" with the parameter like "i=40155", and there is one node shows the attribute I mentioned above.

```
<gemProperties>+12 Spell Power and +10 Haste Rating</gemProperties>
```